# Namely Api filter for field NOT Equal

Tags: filtering, namely

I need to filter results obtained from namely API profiles by using NOT equal to blank (or empty)
So, in my regular response, I get something like

```
....
"field1": "val1"
"field2": ""
"field3": "val3"
"field2": ""
....
```

I know, how to get the **field1** and **field3** by using filter

```
https://namelyBaseURl/api/v1/profiles.json?filter[field1]=val1&filter[field3]=val3
```

But, I need to specify my query in the form that takes "everything that is not empty"
so something, like **field1 != <blank??>**  and I can't find anything in documentation on it.
As you can see, **field2** and **field4** are defined and do show up in the response.
I wanted to use != or <> but it does not work straight out like this.  And I am lost
Isn't it a standard query language ?